# Ag-Grid expand row

Tags: ag-grid

Im using Ag-grid to control my table, but i want in my group that stores a list of  rows instead of having to make the row group expand in 2 clicks, i want to be on 1 click. 
If i click on the icon arrow it works, but if i click on the title row it only opens on 2 clicks.

I already tried to find in the documentation any information about it, but cant find nothing.

Here is a example from the documentation.
https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/index.php

example image:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

We are now recommended not to use the `onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed`, so this should now be...

This will also update the icons and animate the rows, which `onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed` won't.

```
onRowClicked(params) {
    params.node.setExpanded(!params.node.expanded);
}
```

This will toggle the expansion, use `params.node.setExpanded(true)` if you want the rows to just stay open.

Comment: How to disable the double click behaviour for row expansion.?

Answer (score 7):

You can listen to events on either a row or cell clicked, and expand nodes accordingly.

For example to expand a row based on a click you could do the following:

```
onRowClicked: (params) => {
    // update the node to be expanded
    params.node.expanded = true; 
    // tell the grid to redraw based on state of nodes expanded state 
    gridOptions.api.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed(params.rowIndex)
}
```

This should be in the documentation - I'll update it to reflect this information.

Comment: Thanks Sean, for the info, i tried that, but the part that i wish to control is not working, basically what im trying to expand is only in one click is the rest of the row and not the icon, you can check the sceenshot of this link.http://i.imgur.com/hiO54L7.png or the image above, i updated my question.

Comment: Hi @Pedro - the above code should expand the row in one click - I tried it with a grouped example before posting just to verify. If you use this code example does it still not expand with one click? If not, do you have a plunker I can take a look at?

Comment: It is better to use dedicated function `params.node.setExpanded(!params.node.expanded)`, it handles animation as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the [column definition](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/index.php), you can use the `onCellClicked(params)` function to tell it to do something when the cell is clicked. I tried looking for an expand function, but I could only find `expandAll()` which I don't think you will want. So what I would do is just use jquery or simple DOM selection to click on the expand icon inside of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

this one works

```
 onRowClicked(params) { 
    params.context.setExpand.onExpandClicked(params.rowIndex, params.node.rowHeight);
  }
```