# Angular ag-grid expand row to show additional data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

To get this done, I have already referred to row group documentation and some questions like [Ag-Grid expand row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083804/ag-grid-expand-row). However I feel what I am trying to do is a tad different which might need to use row grouping. Here is what I need to do.

My dataset has lot of columns. So In the grid, I only want to show the most useful data in columns. Upon clicking a row/icon etc.. I want the row to expand and show other details as in a normal form view. See below illustration

In that there is a button when clicked the additional data is rendeded under the row. I believe I will need row grouping, column spacing, cell rendering all to be used? Has anyone done something similar?

[image: Ag Grid row expanded data]

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution for this? I am looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can show the master details in ag-grid. There are custom templates as well that can suite your need. Please refer the below link to get more details:
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-custom-detail/